# GemFire getRegion() returns null whereas OQL query gives result

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am using Pivotal GemFire 9.0.0 with 1 Locator and 1 Server. The Server has a Region called "submissions", like below -

```
<gfe:replicated-region id="submissionsRegion" name="submissions" 
statistics="true" template="replicateRegionTemplate">
...
</gfe:replicated-region>
```

I am getting Region as null when executing the following code -

```
Region<K, V> region = clientCache.getRegion("submissions");
```

Surprisingly, the same `ClientCache` returns all the records when I query using OQL and `QueryService` as shown below -

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM /submissions";
QueryService queryService = clientCache.getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
SelectResults results = (SelectResults) query.execute();
```

I am initializing my `ClientCache` like this -

```
ClientCache clientCache = new ClientCacheFactory()
            .addPoolLocator("localhost", 10479)
            .set("name", "MyClientCache")
            .set("log-level", "error")
            .create();
```

I am really baffled by this. Any pointer or help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your **ClientCache** (either through a cache.xml or pure GemFire API) with the regions as well. Using your example:

```
ClientRegionFactory regionFactory = clientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
Region region = regionFactory.create("submissions");
```

The **ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY** is used just for the sake of simplicity, you should use the shortcut that meets your needs.

The OQL works as expected because you are obtaining the **QueryService** through the **ClientCache.getQueryService()** method (instead of **ClientCache.getLocalQueryService()**), so the query is actually executed on Server Side.

You can get more information about how to configure the Client/Server topology in 
[Client/Server Configuration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/cs_configuration/chapter_overview.html).

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Urizen, it worked. However, I did understand what `clientCache.getRegion("submissions")` was doing. Since, I connected to the loactor using `clientCache`, it should have fetched me the region.

Comment: Hi. Did you figure out how to solve it? I'm experiencing same behaviour. getRegion is returning null and ClientCacheFactory RegionExistsException.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to "define" the corresponding client-side Region, matching the server-side `REPLICATE` Region by name (i.e. "submissions").  Actually this is a requirement independent of the server Regions' `DataPolicy` type (e.g. `REPLICATE` or `PARTITION`).

This is necessary since not every client wants to know about or even needs have data/events from every possible server Region.  Of course, this is also configurable through subscription and "Interests Registration" (with [Client/Server Event Messaging](http://gemfire90.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/configure_client_server_event_messaging.html), or alternatively, [CQs](http://gemfire90.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/continuous_querying/chapter_overview.html)).

Anyway, you can completely avoid the use of the GemFire API directly or even GemFire's native `cache.xml` (highly recommend avoiding) by using either SDG's XML namespace...

```
<gfe:client-cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" ... />

<gfe:client-region id="submissions" shortcut="PROXY"/>
```

Or by using *Spring* JavaConfig with SDG's API...

```
@Configuration
class GemFireConfiguration {

  Properties gemfireProperties() {

    Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();

    gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", "config");
    ...

    return gemfireProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {

    ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new ClientCacheFactoryBean();

    gemfireCache.setClose(true);
    gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties());
    ...

    return gemfireCache;
  }

  @Bean(name = "submissions");
  ClientRegionFactoryBean submissionsRegion(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {

    ClientRegionFactoryBean submissions = new ClientRegionFactoryBean();

    submissions.setCache(gemfireCache);
    submissions.setClose(false);
    submissions.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
    ...

    return submissions;
  }

  ...
}
```

The "submissions" Region can be wrapped with SDG's [GemfireTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html), which will handle getting the "correct" `QueryService` on your behalf when running queries using the [find(..)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#find-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method.

Of course, you may be interested in making your client "submissions" Region a `CACHING_PROXY`" too.  Of course, you will then need to register "interests" in the keys or data of interests.  CQs are the best way to do this as it uses query criteria to define the data of "interests".

`CACHING_PROXY` is exactly as it sounds, caching data locally in the client based on the interests policies.  This also gives you the ability to use the "local" `QueryService` to query data locally, avoiding the network hop.

Anyway, many options here.

Cheers,
John